# Mysql : Problem in exporting the database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php and mysql. When i try to export the database using phpMyAdmin. The database have 365 tables. But when i export i'm getting only 209 tables. The exported file size was 120mb. What's the problem exporting the file?? Either i have to change any configuration settings ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to export using linux console with [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). A small tutorial can be found [here](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/mysql/mysqlbackup/mysqldump.html).

Answer (score 2):

there could be multiple problems. memory limit, execution time. I guess 120mb fits exactly your memory limit ;)

try to increase this limit
or try `mysqldump --opt -u username -ppassword database > foobar.sql` on the cli

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried with cmd line it's exporting properly. And same time i have to check with other stuffs also.